# fill the UiPickerView with a previous array created with json GET ( i get '?' instead the data)

Tags: arrays, json, swift, button, uipickerview

i got a problem when i try to show the array in the UiPickerView, i check the array data(that comes from the json) in the console the data is there, but when i try to fill the picker i get '?' (1 for every row of the array)

this is my code

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var NameLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var myPicker: UIPickerView!

var pickerData = [String]()




@IBAction func Butonio(sender: AnyObject) {

    var urlPath: String = "link with json encode response"
    //self.NameLabel.text = urlPath;

    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request1: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request1, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var err: NSError?
       // println(data)


        if let json =  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:
        &err) as? NSArray{

        if let descripcion = json[0]["descripcion"] as? NSString {

            let descripcion2 = NSUUID().UUIDString

            var descripcion3 = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
            let stringo : Int = json.count
             println( "el nmuero es \(stringo)")

           var stringc = ""
           // NSArray colors = [[Int:String]]()
            //var pickerData = [String]()

           var j = 0
            while j == 0{

                if self.pickerData.isEmpty{
                j=1
                } else {
                self.pickerData.removeLast()
                }
            }

                for i in  0..<stringo{
                if let descr =  json[i]["descripcion"] as? NSString{
               //println( "la desc es \(descr)")
               //colors[i] = descr
                //var colors: [Int:String] = [i : descr]
                self.pickerData.append(descr)
                stringc += self.pickerData[i]+" , "
               println( "la desc/  es \(self.pickerData[i])")
                    }

            }

            self.myPicker.dataSource = self
            self.myPicker.delegate = self


            self.myPicker.reloadAllComponents()



            println( "la desc/total  es \(stringc)")

            return


            }


        }

    })



}


//MARK: - Delegates and data sources
//MARK Data Sources

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.pickerData.count
}


//MARK Delegate
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, tittleForRow row: Int, forComponet component: Int) -> String!{
     //println(row)
    return self.pickerData[row]

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, forComponet component: Int) {
   //println(row)
  println( "la desc/  es \(self.pickerData[row])")
    // self.NameLabel.text = self.pickerData[row]
}
```

}

Comment: in adition to all this i cant make the last part to work "func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, forComponet component: Int) {

  println( "la desc/  es \(self.pickerData[row])")
   

}"  but i dont know if it do not work because i cant make the uipickerview work correctly or its wrong in some point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the delegate and data source func had some problems and this are the correct way of using them

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    NameLabel.text = pickerData[row]
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```